# Replace numerical values by Dates (format dd-mm-yyyy) in R

Tags: r, date

I seek to do the following. In my dataset, I have the variable "exact_date". At the moment, it is coded with numerical values that each stand for a specific date, e.g. '1' stands for 'February 19th, 2019' and so on.

I'd like to replace those numerical values (1-15) with the actual dates in the format (dd-mm-yyyy). I've tried a lot of commands, as for instance

```
gsub("1", "19-02-2019", dataset$exact_date)
```

which doesn't yield the desired outcome.

Similarly,

```
dataset$exact_date[dataset$exact_date == 1] <- as.character("19-02-2019")
```

or

```
library(tidyverse)
pre_911 %>% mutate_at(
  vars(
    c('exact_date')
  ),
  funs(
    case_when(
     
      . = 2              ~ '20/02/2019',
      . = 3            ~ '21/02/2019',
      TRUE               ~ as.character(.)
    )
  )
)
```

do not produce the desired output.

Can someone help me achieve what I want?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "and so on"? It's not clear what the pattern is.

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The operator `+` accepts dates. So the following represents the number of days after `2019-02-18`.

```r
as.Date("2019-02-18") + as.integer(dataset$exact_date)
```

If they represent specific dates, you can use the numbers as an index

```r
dates <- as.Date(c("2019-02-19", "2019-02-20", <other dates>))
dates[as.integer(dataset$exact_date)]
```

Comment: Hi, a big thanks to you as well. Again, running your first line of code produces a satisfying output in the console, which is unfortunately not transferred to my actual dataset when typing View(pre_911). What's the matter there?
Similarly, running your second box looks very promising in the console but frustrating when looking at my dataset.

Comment: Did you assign the column back to `dataset`?  `dataset$exact_date <- as.Date("2019-02-18") + as.integer(dataset$exact_date)`?

Comment: Hugh, thanks. Could you post the full code you'd advise me to run (having incorporated your most previous suggestion)? Having looked at codes for the past several hours, I'm a bit lost at the moment. I'd greatly appreciate that. I'll be able to run it when I get home again in two hours.

Comment: Follow up:

dates <- as.Date(c("2019-02-19", "2019-02-20"))
dates[as.integer(pre_911$exact_date)]
pre_911$exact_date <- as.Date("2019-02-18") + as.integer(pre_911$exact_date)

This worked! But, looking over my dataset, it seems to jump from 2019-02-27 directly to 2019-03-01, hence leaving out 2019-02-28... Why might that be?

Comment: In your question, please post `dput(head(pre_911))` and `dput(unique(pre_911$exact_date))` on the original data

Comment: Hi Hugh, I think I found out what the problem was. At the moment, "exact_date" is coded numerically from 1-9 and 11-15. The number 10 is left out, which probably messes up the dates to be assigned to the numbers. I'll try to recode the variable so that the gap disappears, and then re-run your code. 
Again, a big big thanks for your help, I greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

Turn the numerical values to dates with origin as `'2019-02-18'`

```
dataset <- data.frame(exact_date =  c(2, 1, 3, 4, 1))
as.Date(dataset$exact_date, origin = '2019-02-18')
#[1] "2019-02-20" "2019-02-19" "2019-02-21" "2019-02-22" "2019-02-19"
```

If you want dates in dmy format you can use `format`

```
format(as.Date(dataset$exact_date, origin = '2019-02-18'), '%d/%m/%Y')
#[1] "20/02/2019" "19/02/2019" "21/02/2019" "22/02/2019" "19/02/2019"
```

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot! Analogously to my answer below, running your first line of code makes my dataset shrink and lose all relevant information. Hence, the code again doesn't produce the desired outcome.

Comment: You need to assign the output to one column. `dataset$date <- as.Date(dataset$exact_date, origin = '2019-02-18')` which will keep all the information in the data intact adding a new column `date` to the dataset. Moreover, you have not shared any relevant data or even your desired outcome for us to know what you expect. All the answers here have created our own interpretation of your data.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, Ronak. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example using `mutate`.

```
library(tidyverse)

dataset <- tibble(exact_date = c(2, 3, 1))

new_tibble <- dataset %>%
    mutate(exact_date = 
        case_when(
            exact_date == 1            ~ '19/02/2019',
            exact_date == 2            ~ '20/02/2019',
            exact_date == 3            ~ '21/02/2019',
            TRUE                       ~ as.character(exact_date)
        )
    )
new_tibble
# A tibble: 3 x 1
  exact_date
  <chr>     
1 20/02/2019
2 21/02/2019
3 19/02/2019
```

Comment: First of all, thanks a lot for your effort. However, if I copy your code and run it, my dataset loses all information and due to the code in the second line, only consists of one variable and three observations ...

Secondly, if I only start copying the code starting from "pre_911 %>%"..., the output in the console is the correct one, but it doesn't transfer to my actual dataset when I type View(pre_911). That's actually a problem I had with several commands, namely that the console output was good but the dataset stayed unchanged.

Comment: You should strive to make standalone reproducible examples because there's no way anyone can know what the impact of setting variables to specific values will be on your own private code. I've changed the example to explicitly set a new variable rather than echo it.

Comment: Hi Andrew, you're definitely right. I'm sorry for the way I formulated my question. As you have probably noticed, I'm a beginner with R that unfortunately only received a brief introduction (during my bachelor's studies) and now has to tackle harder issues. 
Having said that, thanks a lot for your help given the circumstances! If you happen to know any kind of tutorial/book for playing around with R (that goes beyond my regression introduction I received), I'd be happy if you could share it.

Comment: Questions asking for recommendations are generally outside the scope of StackOverflow. That said, there isn't one site I would recommend apart from Google (and StackOverflow of course).